# Why does ordering rows lessen the row count in an explain?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, explain, mysql5, mysql-5.5

I have a table with some two or three million rows…

```
mysql> select count(*) from tbl;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  2615889 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.23 sec)

mysql> show indexes from tbl;
+-------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name          | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tbl   |          0 | PRIMARY           |            1 | tbl_id      | A         |     2284627 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| ...
| tbl   |          1 | tbl_fld           |            1 | fld         | A         |     2284627 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.30 sec)
```

…and for the following query I seem to do drastically better (namely, I wind up using an index) if I add an `order by` clause…

```
mysql> explain select * from tbl
    -> where fld in (select fld from tbl group by fld having count(*)>1)
    -> limit 1000;
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | tbl   | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 2328333 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl   | index | NULL          | tbl_fld | 15      | NULL |       1 | Using index |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from tbl
    -> where fld in (select fld from tbl group by fld having count(*)>1)
    -> order by fld limit 1000;
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | tbl   | index | NULL          | tbl_fld | 15      | NULL | 1000 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl   | index | NULL          | tbl_fld | 15      | NULL |    1 | Using index |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

… why is that?

Comment: Did you run the queries or just compare their plans? I don't think MySQL will actually scan the whole table in your first query. The LIMIT will make it much faster.

Comment: @Tim3880, just `explain`.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance, it looks like it's using a key in the second query which is a good thing so that it will prevent a full scan of the table.

Comment: I mentioned that in the question. The question was *why* is it planning to use an index in the second but not the first query.

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT should not be used without ORDER BY as then it is not well-defined which rows will be returned. And as you found out [ORDER BY .. LIMIT optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html) does not work (is not implemented at all AFAIK), whereas when you add ORDER BY, the optimization kicks in and MySQL stops executing after enough rows are found.

Comment: I don't see anything relevant on the page you link to; what part of that page are you referring to?

Comment: You are right, This exact situation is not covered on that page better than "As soon as MySQL has sent the required number of rows to the client, it aborts the query" - it says that both the queries should be similarly fast, the one NOT using index might be even faster in some cases. MySQL has no way to decide which rows might match the subquery (as it is evaluated as DEPENDENT) so it prefers full table scan when no ordering is needed - as the probability to found 1000 rows fast is the same going any way and table scan is usually optimal for disk IO (it is mostly sequential scan).

Comment: Everything might change if you rewrite the subquery to materialized/derived table instead of dependent. That way it is possible to do the subquery as index-only scan and then pick the relevant 1000 rows by that index directly.